# QMetaObject::invokeMethod: no such method QTextCursor::MoveOperation,QTextCursor::MoveMode

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Upon using the following code in a 2-threaded QT program in c++ I get this runtime error (program keeps running though):

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod: no such method QTextCursor::MoveOperation,QTextCursor::MoveMode
```

the code:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(textEdit, "moveCursor", Qt::QueuedConnection,
        Q_ARG(QTextCursor::MoveOperation, QTextCursor::End),
        Q_ARG(QTextCursor::MoveMode, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor));
```

(textEdit is a QTextEdit object).

I know that only invokable functions/slots can be invoked. Even looking at QT's source code I couldn't figure if this function is not invokable. 
What am I doing wrong?
Is there any other way of moving the cursor to the end from another thread if this method really is not invokable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QTextEdit::moveCursor()` is neither a slot nor is marked as invokable. But only slots and functions marked with `Q_INVOKABLE` can be called using `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`.

Either implement your own slot in an object in the target thread.
Or use `QTimer::singleShot()` withe a delay of 0, it has an overload that take a function pointer and works with non slot functions.

On a side note, looking at Qt sources to find slots or invokable functions is pretty easy as it can be seen directly at the function declaration. Here are some examples:

```
// a() is a normal function
public:
    void a();

// b(), c() and d() are slots
public slots:
    void b();

public Q_SLOTS:
    void c();

public:
    Q_SLOT void d();

// e() is invokable
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void e();
```